# using background process in php

Tags: php, multithreading, node.js, process, exec

I am trying to import large number of tweets from Twitter by a user, so I want that when user clicks on Import I start a background process that can import tweets for the user, considering PHP is not multithreaded , what I can do to achieve this task, After googling i came across `exec` command , is that the only option, do we have better libraries around?

- What I want to create is job handler in the backend so user can continue surfing the site meanwhile his tweets are being imported in DB?
  Thanks

Comment: Google "background process php" - Many hits. Here's one result http://stackoverflow.com/q/45953/

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have gone through it asmentioned the exec solution "Write the process as a server-side script in whatever language (php/bash/perl/etc) is handy and then call it from the process control functions in your php script." but is this the only option.?

Comment: What does multithreading have to do with this task?

Comment: https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon - (background process php daemon) and http://tt-rss.org/redmine/projects/tt-rss/wiki/UpdatingFeeds as an example.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque

Comment: @JayBlanchard I thought its all because php is not multithreaded that we need solutions like that :)